# How to access grailsApplication config in Config.groovy

Tags: grails

Is there a way to get properties from `grailsApplication.config` from *inside* `Config.groovy`?
(I'm using Grails 2.0.3)

**Working**
Using `grailsApplication`, I can get config values in `resources.groovy`:

```
def cfg = grailsApplication.config
someBean(SomeClass){
  foo = cfg.smpt.host
}
```

**Not Working**
But in `Config.groovy`, it doesn't work; returns empty maps for `host` and `port` values:

```
    //Config.groovy
    def cfg = grailsApplication.config
    grails {
       mail {
         host   = cfg.smtp.host  //empty value!
         port   = cfg.smtp.port  //empty value!
       }
    }
```

**Workaround**
Moved mail config into custom config file, and referenced properties locally, without `grailsApplication`:

```
//myconfig.groovy (dev)
smtp.host
smtp.port

grails {
   mail {
      host   = smtp.host
      port   = smtp.port
   }
}
```

This works, but forces me to repeat mail config in each config file for dev, qa, uat, prod, creating duplicate configuration.

Why does `grailsApplication.config` work in `resources.groovy`, but doesn't in `Config.groovy`?

Comment: Duplicate question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20754029/2051952). Use `grails.util.Holders`.

Comment: I read that `ConfigurationHolder` was deprecated, is `Holders` the replacement for 2.0?

Answer (score 1):

```
//Config.groovy 
grails.smtp.host = HOST
grails.smtp.port = PORT
//we can use  
grails.mail.host = grails.smtp.host
grails.mail.port = grails.smtp.port
```